# Yii Dropdownlist- show response array as values

Tags: php, ajax, yii

After an ajax request i got one array from my controller as response, how can I use this array values in my dropdown list?

### Answer

in my view I have

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('client_id', '',CHtml::listData($model,'client_id','client_name'), array(
'ajax'=> array(
'type'=>'POST',
'url'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php?r=page/dynamicDropdownList',
'update'=>'#program_id',
'empty'=>'-Select a Client-')));

// I need to populate the response array in this dropdownlist
echo CHtml::dropDownList('program_id','', CHtml::listData($result,'program_id', 'program_name'));
```

in my controller

```
 public function actionDynamicDropdownList()
 {

    if($_POST['client_id'] > '0') {
        $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('program_id, program_name')->from('program')->where('client_id='.$_POST['client_id'].'')->order('program_name')->queryAll();
        $this->render('admin', array(
            'result' => $result,
        ));

    }

   }
```

### Another Problem

Now I got everything working except the second drop downlist is also showing the values of 1st dropdown list with the result.

solution:- I have parse the response and show it in the dropdownlist

Comment: i just did "echo $result" from my controller, but how can I access this response?

Comment: please paste code, as i dont understand you; we need code, to help you

Comment: 1. never ever do that in a view; you load the data, in the controller, and you pass it to the views; 2. this is how a dropdiwn list looks like : <? echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'position_type', CHtml::listData(PositionType::model()->findAll(array('condition' => 'status=1')), 'id', 'name'), array('class' => 'postdropdown2', 'empty' => array(-1 => 'All'), 'onchange' => 'showDiv(this.value,1);')); ?>

Comment: i dont know why you get the same results; also, dont do queryes in views; also, use criterias when using query

Comment: yes i know, I will move that query to the controller. Actually everything is working now, but still have one problem the second and 3rd dropdownlist showing the entire option values, like the second dropdown list is populated with new query results plus the options in the 1st dropdown list. same case for the 3rd dropdownlist also. do you know why its coming like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your controller should look like:

```
public function actionIndex() {

        $model = new SearchForm();
        if ($_GET['SearchForm']) {
            $model->attributes = $_GET['SearchForm'];
        }

//here is where you put your criteria or query commands

        if ($_GET['ajax']) {
            $this->renderPartial('index', array(
                'model' => $model,
            ));
        } else {

            $this->render('index', array(
                'model' => $model,
            ));
        }
    }
```

You catch the data from ajax or GET and you do something with it, then you pas the data to the view;

And this should be what the vies contains:

```
<? echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'position_type', CHtml::listData(PositionType::model()->findAll(array('condition' => 'status=1')), 'id', 'name'), array('class' => 'postdropdown2', 'empty' => array(-1 => 'All'), 'onchange' => 'showDiv(this.value,1);')); ?>
```

You have to work with data received using ajax in the controller, as it is not visible in the view, if it was not passed using render or renderpartial

Comment: actually the model which i have used in my controller is not an active record of it, what should I do in this situaltion?

Comment: if it is not an active record, then the model does not exist, and Yii does not know how to work with it

Comment: i dont think so, because yii works with active records; if yii does not know about it, it cant work with it

Comment: use gii to generate model, and then, work with the model, use the find methods

Comment: actually everything is working perfectly  now except the second dropbox is showing option values of 1st dropdown also

Comment: I have added it in my question, please see that.